# Leftover Juicing Pulp in Beer?

Tags: techniques, ingredients, fruit, recipe-formulation

I'm a very new homebrewer and this may be a really wacky question, but I'm curious nonetheless. Every time I've made fresh juice using a juicer, I'm at a loss for what to do with the leftover pulp, and I feel bad throwing it away. I'd read of recipes utilizing the pulp in bread or muffins, but I'm not much of a baker. But, I was wondering if the pulp could possibly be used in a homebrew. Obviously, there's loads of beer being made with fruits and spices,but has anyone heard of pulp in particular being used? Any insight on when would be a good time to add it to the wort/beer? While boiling and adding malt? Right before starting fermentation? Any insight would be really appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect adding all that pulp only you'll get hazy beer from all the fruit tannins.  And those tannins may lead to a weird astringency depending on the type of fruit.

But to experiment, I'd add it in secondary.  Adding it at boils end would certainly generate pectin haze.

It might not hurt to run some sanitizer through the juicer first.

Answer (score 0):

Check out other questions on adding fruit to beer:

[How to add fruit to beer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/490/how-to-add-fruit-to-beer?rq=1)

I would guess though that if you're adding just fruit skins, then your beer is going to be sour.

Comment: "*your beer is going to be sour*" Maybe the OP should just eat a handful of the pulp as-is. If it tastes OK, then it's worth of being added to the wort. If not, then maybe dump it... Would that be a decent guideline?